# Как удалить недоустановленную Ubuntu и ее диск?

Tags: ubuntu

Скачала virtialbox и ubuntu. Последняя на выборе языка зависла. Хочу ее удалить и заново поставить, но как это сделать? Вижу что она занимает место на диске, есть CD-ROM Ubuntu 16.04.6, как это добро удалить, помогите чайнику.(

Comment: Удалите созданную виртуальную машину в интерфейсе virtualbox

Comment: Удалила, но в управлении дисками она есть , и ярлык тоже не удаляется, пишет она открыта в системе

Comment: Что вы имеете в виду под управлением дисками?

Comment: В управлении компьютером весь список дисков, она там висит тоже.  Хотя в виртуалбокс пусто

Comment: Нажмите на него правой кнопкой и выберете пункт "извлечь". Зачет файл можно будет удалить

Comment: Извлекла, но остался ярлык на рабочем столе ubuntu-16.04.6-desktop-amd64.iso тип файл образа диска, размер 1,54 гига, удалить нельзя, так как он открыт в system

Comment: Возможно, он все еще используется virtualbox. Вы можете выключить ее и попробовать удалить еще раз

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, удалила, включив безопасный режим. Еще есть вопрос, убунту вирт.машина и ОС убунту это разные вещи? Для удаления последней нужно чуть ли не установочный диск видновс и так далее. Виртуальная машина удаляется с помощью виртуалбокс. Я верно понимаю?